# Ubuntu doesn't change the keyboard layout

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-layout

On Ubuntu 20.04 I have installed two keyboard layouts (RU and EN). Sometimes(quite often) I face an issue with changing the layout(mostly happens after the Suspend period): when I want to change the layout it keeps the EN layout when I type although in the system tray it shows that language is changed to RU.
[image]
**A workaround** that I found is to open the *Region & Language* settings and change the order of the *Input Sources*. **This workaround is temporary**, so next time it happens I need to do that again (in my case is changing the order of 2 layouts in **EN->RU** placeholder simply by drag and drop and when it happens again, switch back **RU->EN**, so I guess the order itself doesn't matter).
[image: keyboard layout]
I assume it might be related to some cache or setting that is cleaned or updated once I change the layout order or add a new language.

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Mine was more permanent, but switching their position worked for the time being. If it stops working again I will write back here.

Comment: Add languages in “Input Source Options” In Ubuntu Settings